# Squid proxy: authorize some site without authentication

Tags: proxy, squid

I have a Squid proxy and I am using `auth_param basic program` with `ncsa_auth`.

I would like the user to access some specified sites, like google.com and yahoo.com, without asking them to provide proxy credentials, meaning that when users type google.com in the browser, the site will be opened immediately, without requesting proxy username and password.

Other sites will be accessed normally, using proxy credentials.

How to configure Squid for this scenario?

Comment: Any solutions please?

Comment: Why the down-vote? This is a valid use case. E.g. Visual Studio 2022 has a lengthy whitelist of sites, and does not support proxy authentication with username and password, but why disable credential based auth just because one software? Hence the request for hybrid-mode proxy auth.

Answer (score 1):

You should add an acl for the permited addresses on top of your auth lines in squid.conf, i.e for google: 
`acl GOOGLE dstdomain google.com
http_access allow GOOGLE`

That should do it. Remember to add this lines before any auth lines in squid.conf

Comment: MAT I have already did it but even I gave permit access for google.com squid also ask users to login and when they pressed cancel it works but every click asking so it's really disturbing the users do you have another solution?Thanks

Comment: That's because there are other domains involved. Have a look at your access.log and you'll see requests for others domains when you access to Google.